# Problems passing data to jquery's getJSON() - Will not accept map

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, getjson, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to serialize my form (JSP/Struts 1.1) and put it into an object or map or whatever jQuery's .getJSON() method needs.  Here is my js code:

```
// This function makes an AJAX call, passing the entire form to the Action class
function ajaxCallWithForm(inputURL, formName, onReturnFunction)
{
    var formAsMap = serializeForm(formName);     
    $.getJSON(inputURL, formAsMap, onReturnFunction);
}

function serializeForm(formName)
{
    var obj = {};
    var a = $('#'+formName).serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function() {
        if (obj[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!obj[this.name].push) {
                obj[this.name] = [obj[this.name]];
            }
            obj[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            obj[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

This results in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` on the back end (something to do with the BeanUtils.populate servlet method).

If I set the 2nd of 3 parameters of my .getJSON() call to something like this, it works fine and the data shows up in the form object in my Java back end:

```
// This function makes an AJAX call, passing the entire form to the Action class
function ajaxCallWithForm(inputURL, formName, onReturnFunction)
{
    $.getJSON(inputURL, {"vehicleKeyNum":12345,
                         "vehicleID":"12345",
                         "rand":Math.random()}, 
        onReturnFunction);
}
```

I have also tried creating a string with the proper syntax that includes the data from the form and that results in the same thing.  I may have my syntax wrong for that.  At any rate, my main problem is that:

1) The .getJSON() method accepts, "A map or string that is sent to the server with the request." as its 2nd parameter (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

2) I am passing what I think is a "map"

3) I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and don't know where to go from here

Comment: Use Firebug or some other tools to see exactly what the HTTP request looks like, or use logging tools on the server side to do that.

Comment: Exactly, update the question with what json data was posted and the java server side code which is related to the parsing.

Comment: Have you tried just using the jQuery "serialize" method on the form instead of an object?

Comment: I have used the serialize method on the form instead of an object, yes. I get the same error actually. I can try to start using FirebugLite. Here at work we only use IE.  But, if there are any other ways to figure it out, I am open for those ideas, too.

Comment: Both your method and the `.serialize()` and `.serializeArray()` methods should work. Is the problem on the server and not related to jQuery?

Comment: This is quite possible because .serialize() does not work for me (as submitted by Lobo or the many other examples online).  I think it could be something else.  I found in Array.java itself that an IllegalArgumentException happens "if the array is not an array or the value cannot be converted to the array type by a widening".

Comment: I should mention that I know this from the stack trace: 
[6/12/12 14:54:58:935 CDT] 00000026 webapp E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[action]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.lang.reflect.Array.setImpl(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Array.java:272) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils.convert(ConvertUtils.java:415) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:983) at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)

Comment: 1 more clue is that when I change the call in the serializeForm method to just .serialize(), there is no error, but the form is empty once it gets to my action class: `function serializeForm(formName) { var obj = {}; var a = $('#'+formName).serialize(); ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit a form to server, you can simply use jQuery's [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) OR [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method.

```
$.getJSON(inputURL, $(formName).serialize(), onReturnFunction);
```

You should have the data returned by the serialize/serializeArray method populated in your form bean if the element names are matched right.

[here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pd9Ea/) of serialize method (copied from jQuery website)

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` from the `BeanUtils.populate` servlet method is due to data type mismatch between the data submitted and the data on the form bean.

Comment: Thanks Lobo, you are right. My Action Form had a Date[] attribute in it which we cannot do.  I believe we use Date elsewhere in our application and so I'm guessing an action form will accept that, but a Date[] cannot be converted properly from normal, serialized data.  I had assumed that the `.serialize()` method was not giving data in the proper format to `.getJSON()` because the breakpoint at the beginning of my action class was never reached.